# Pergunta para si mesmo e responde para ninguém

Tags: debate, perguntas

tenho visto frequentemente no StackOverflow em Português, pessoas criando threads já com respostas, **na mesma hora**, ou seja, a mesma pessoa que criou, responde.

Acho isto bom, pois por um lado gera conteúdo, mas por outro lado, tira a oportunidade de outras pessoas poderem participar e ajudar na versão beta (que estamos experimentando ainda).

A impressão que passa, é que as pessoas estão fazendo isto apenas por pontos...

Sei que a própria Stack Exchange espera isto dos participantes, mas pelo fato de estarmos em beta e testando, seria legal a pessoa criar e se depois de pelo menos 24 horas não haver uma resposta, ai sim, postar uma solução cabível.

O que vocês acham?

Comment: Tem uma discussão sobre isso: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/37/respondi-minha-propria-pergunta-fiz-algo-errado

Comment: Blza, valeu, fechei a pergunta aqui!